# Transposing first column in dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to Python and I just do pretty basic stuff. So when I managed to sort this out by myself I was really chuffed, although I am not sure if this is the most pythonic way to do it.
I had a csv file that contained this information when read the normal way:
[image: original dataframe]

I wanted the items in the first-row to be the column headers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I used Transpose:

```
df_t=df.T
```

And save it as a new file, without the header to remove the existing headings.

```
df_t.to_csv('employment.csv)
```

When opening the new file, this is what I have:
[image: new dataframe]

As I said, not the most pythonic, but it seems to work. Any suggestions on how to improve this, will be most appreciated.